# Delay in Milliseconds, ARM processor, Code in C

Tags: c, arm, embedded

I'm new to embedded, learning the basics of timer delays. 
I'm on a mini2440 board of FriendlyARM, with a S3C2440A microprocessor.

Wrote the following code to enable a user-defined delay, in milli-seconds, and inserted print to screen for debugging. The code seems to print all the correct numbers, but the actual delay does not work. Would appreciate some pointers.

```
#include "PWMRegs.h"
#include "types.h"
#include "Utils.h"

static U32 PLCK = 50000000;

void MilliDelay(unsigned long mills){

U32 PrescalarMask   =   0xFF << 8; //prescalar 1 for timers 2, 3, & 4
U32 DividerMask     =   0xF << 16; //divider (MUX 4) for timer 4
U32 Prescalar       =   255;
U32 Divider         =   2;
U32 TotSteps;
U32 StepsPerMil;
U32 Current;
U32 Prev;
U32 ElapsedSteps    =   0;

Util_Printf("mills: %u\n", mills);
Util_Printf("PLCK: %u\n", PLCK);
Util_Printf("Divider: %u\n", Divider);
Util_Printf("Prescalar: %u\n", Prescalar);


//Timer configuration
*TCFG0 &= ~PrescalarMask;           //zero out prescalar
*TCFG0 |=  PrescalarMask;           //prescalar 255
*TCFG1 &=  ~DividerMask;            //zero out divider
*TCFG1 |=  TIMER4_MUX_1_2;          //divider 1/2

StepsPerMil = PLCK/(1000*Divider*(Prescalar+1));
Uart_Printf("Steps per Mil: %d\n", StepsPerMil);
TotSteps = StepsPerMil*mills;
Uart_Printf("Tot Steps: %d\n", TotSteps);


*TCNTB4 = StepsPerMil;  

*TCON |= (TIMER4_START | TIMER4_MAN_UPDATE | TIMER4_AUTO_RELOAD); //autoload, update TCNTB4, start timer 4
*TCON &= ~(TIMER4_MAN_UPDATE);      //clear manual update bit
Prev = *TCNTO4;
Uart_Printf("\nInitial TCNTO4: %d \n", Prev);
while(ElapsedSteps < TotSteps){
    Current = *TCNTO4;
    if (Current <= Prev)
    {
        ElapsedSteps += Current + (StepsPerMil - Prev);
    }
    else
        ElapsedSteps += Current - Prev;
    Prev = Current;
}

/* Stop the timer */    
*TCON &= ~(TIMER4_START | TIMER4_AUTO_RELOAD);
Uart_Printf("Elapsed Steps: %d \n", ElapsedSteps);

}

void TestTimer(){
    Util_Printf("You've entered the timer delay test.\n");
    Util_Printf("Enter delay in milli-seconds:\t");
    unsigned long mills = Util_GetIntNum();

    MilliDelay(mills);
}
```

Here's an example of what prints:

0-Test Regsiter read word
1-Test Regsiter write word
2-Test Regsiter read byte
3-Test Regsiter write byte
4-Test Read DM9000 ID
5-Test GPIO ID
6-Test Timer
6
You've entered the timer delay test.
Enter delay in milli-seconds:   1000
mills: 1000
PLCK: 50000000
Divider: 2
Prescalar: 255
Steps per Mil: 97
Tot Steps: 97000

Initial TCNTO4: 83
Elapsed Steps: 97060

Comment: What do you mean the actual delay does not work? Are you talking about expecting 97000 steps, but it actually stepped 97060 steps?

Comment: No, the program does not experience an actual delay, which should occur between printing of "Initial TCNTO4" and printing "Elapsed Steps", but in fact it prints immediately. I've tried making a 10000 ms (10sec) delay and still prints immediately.

Comment: Seems your timer is not set up correctly. Can you put a breakpoint in your code? Is all the registers set up correctly? You can try to point the timer to an GPIO pin, and see if the frequency is what you expect.

Comment: Hein, I think I figured it out. I was assuming that the counter counts up instead of down and had the calculation wrong.

Comment: Instead of
ElapsedSteps += Current + (StepsPerMil - Prev);
It should be: ElapsedSteps += (Prev - Current);
Which now, the program experiences a delay. Thanks for the help. Got me thinking.

Comment: Where is `Util_GetIntNum` defined, and what does it do?

Comment: Let's say it is a 16-bit timer. If it is counting up then `U16 diff = current - prev;` and if counting down then `U16 diff = prev - current;` followed by `elapsed += diff; prev = currrent;`. Unsigned overflow is guaranteed to wrap.

Comment: @ryyker Util_GetIntNum is defined in a separate header file which I didn't paste. But it simply waits for user to input an "int"

Comment: @WeatherVane : right, but let's say we're counting down and the counter overflowed such that the current is now a larger number than the prev, have to take that into account also. that's why there's a condition written into it

Comment: The timer counters typically wrap. The subtraction overflow is handled correctly. Also why I calculated `diff` separately for the same data size as the register. Your code is needlessly convoluted. Try me! `prev` and `current` should also be the correct size for the counter register.

Comment: @WeatherVane : I don’t understand how you are handling the overflow without setting conditions. If it’s counting down, and it overflowed, diff = prev - current may turn out to be negative. How does that work then?

Comment: Because unsigned  values are not negative, they wrap. For example if the timer count goes down from `0x0002` to `0xFFFF` then `0x0002 - 0xFFFF` = `0xFFFF0003` but the upper nibbles `0xFFFF` are discarded leaving the correct `0x0003`, provided it is done in a 16-bit variable.

Comment: for a free running timer to get you the right difference you need to mask with the size of the counter, if it is a 24 bit counter then (x-y)*0x00FFFFFF; otherwise you wont get the correct difference.  doesnt hurt to always add this as a habit, the compiler can optimize it out if the mask size matches or exceeds the size of the variables used.

Comment: @WeatherVane : I see what you’re saying.  the upper nibbles are discarded assuming it’s on a system running little endian, or is that irrelevant here?

Comment: endianness is not relevant - those upper nibbles only exist in the case that old_timer mentioned, which as he says, so long as the variables are unsigned you can use U32 and simply mask off the unwanted part.

Comment: @WeatherVane : I changed the code. Now Current & Prev are 16-bit vars, I'm masking the difference,  and simplified the while loop to the following

     while(ElapsedSteps < TotSteps){
  Current = *TCNTO4;
  ElapsedSteps += (Prev - Current) & 0xFFFF;
  Prev = Current;
 }

Comment: I must've done something off, because now the result is worse:

You've entered the timer delay test.                                            
Enter delay in milli-seconds:   100                                             
mills: 100
PLCK: 50000000  
Divider: 2                                                          
Prescalar: 255
Steps per Mil: 97
Tot Steps: 9700 
Initial TCNTO4: 0
Final Elapsed Steps: 65525

Comment: And if I don't mask it, just leave ElapsedSteps += Prev - Current
then it goes into infinite loop

Comment: I would calculate the difference as a separate instruction as in my original comment.

Comment: Still a no go, i tried the following:

     while(ElapsedSteps < TotSteps){
  Current = *TCNTO4;
  Diff = Prev - Current;
  ElapsedSteps += (Diff & 0x0000FFFF);
  Prev = Current;
 }

Comment: And getting this result:

You've entered the timer delay test.       
Enter delay in milli-seconds:   100      
mills: 100
PLCK: 50000000                     
Divider: 2                         
Prescalar: 255                       
Steps per Mil: 97                                                               
Tot Steps: 9700                                                                 
                                                                                
Initial TCNTO4: 0 

Final Elapsed Steps: 65525

Comment: In that trial I declared Prev, Current, & Diff as 16-bit vars